# JUnit, @ControllerAdvice and lack of checked exceptions in Kotlin

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, spring-aop, kotlin-interop

I wrote a [validation advisor](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-aop-aspectj-annotation-example/) in Kotlin which throws `EntityValidationException` when validation fails:

```
@Aspect
@Named
class ValidationAdvisor
@Inject constructor(val validator: EntityValidator) {
    @Around(EVERY_SAVE_AND_UPDATE_TO_DATABASE)
    fun validate(point: ProceedingJoinPoint): Any {
        val result: List<ConstraintViolation<Any>> = validator.validate(getEntity(point))
        if (isEntityValid(result))
            return point.proceed()

        throw EntityValidationException(
            violationInfos = result as List<ConstraintViolationInfo>
        )
    }

    private fun getEntity(point: ProceedingJoinPoint): Any {
        return point.args[0]
    }

    private fun isEntityValid(result: List<ConstraintViolation<Any>>): Boolean {
        return result.isEmpty()
    }

    companion object {
        const val EVERY_SAVE_AND_UPDATE_TO_DATABASE = "execution(* beans.repositories.BaseRepository.save(..))"
    }
}
```

I have a JUnit test (I write some parts in Kotlin and some in Java, to learn Kotlin in existing private project) which checks if exception is thrown:

```
@Test(expected = EntityValidationException.class)
public void test_WhenNameIsNotPresent_ThenExceptionIsThrown() throws Exception {
    repository.save(/* entity to save */);
}
```

But then I saw that test fails because it throws [UndeclaredThrowableException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/UndeclaredThrowableException.html) instead of `EntityValidationException`. Next, I read that [Kotlin does not have checked exception](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/exceptions.html#checked-exceptions). I think not only me have this problem - I am pretty sure that [way of handling exceptions with @ControllerAdvice in Spring and Java](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc#global-exception-handling) also may be problematic when we decide to switch to Kotlin in production projects - because it rely on class which is thrown, and throwing `UndeclaredThrowableException` take away from us this possibility. Is there a way to by-pass this behaviour, to make sure that is possible to switch to Kotlin and *old* Spring way of handling exceptions (and unit tests for `ValidationAdvisor`) will remain unchanged? Thank you in advance for any help.

**P.S.** Github repo for project is available here: [Playgroud for Kotlin, Spring Data etc.](https://github.com/radek-anuszewski/film-site).

**P.S.2** Stacktrace:

```
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy65.save(Unknown Source)
    at ActorValidationTest.test_WhenNameIsNotPresent_ThenExceptionIsThrown(ActorValidationTest.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.ExpectException.evaluate(ExpectException.java:19)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: beans.validator.exceptions.EntityValidationException
    at beans.aop.validation.ValidationAdvisor.validate(ValidationAdvisor.kt:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:618)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    ... 37 more
```

For me looks like `EntityValidationException` (which I want to be thrown) causes `UndeclaredThrowableException`.
`EntityValidationException` Kotlin class code:

```
package beans.validator.exceptions

import beans.validator.constraintViolation.ConstraintViolationInfo

class EntityValidationException (val violationInfos: List<ConstraintViolationInfo>) : Exception() {
}
```

**P.S.3** This also didn't work:

```
@Around(EVERY_SAVE_AND_UPDATE_TO_DATABASE)
@Throws(EntityValidationException::class)
fun validate(point: ProceedingJoinPoint): Any /* rest of code*/
```

**P.S.4** Maybe the problem is that `@Aspect` is `@Around` Spring Data repository?

```
companion object {
        const val EVERY_SAVE_AND_UPDATE_TO_DATABASE = "execution(* beans.repositories.BaseRepository.save(..))"
    }
....
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRepository<ENTITY, IDENTIFIER extends Serializable>
        extends JpaRepository<ENTITY, IDENTIFIER>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<ENTITY> {
}
```

Comment: In runtime checked exceptions doesn't exists. And checked exceptions exists only in compile time. Please show stack trace of `UndeclaredThrowableException`.

Comment: @IRus Question updated with stack trace - `EntityValidationException` is thrown intentionally, but problem is with `UndeclaredThrowableException` - `EntityValidationException` is written also in Kotlin and I will update question with its code within few seconds.

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-throws/

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you, but unfortunately it didn't help, annotation `@Throws(EntityValidationException::class)` don't work on `validate` method of `ValidatorAdvisor`. Maybe reason is that I use also `@Around` annotation, but even when I separate code to private method with annotation `@Throws` it didn't work either.

Comment: Maybe problem is that I created `@Aspect` `@Around` Spring Data repository?

Comment: Downloaded your project and can't find this test in it. Can you publish it as well?

Comment: @IRus I see test in repo: https://github.com/radek-anuszewski/film-site/blob/master/src/main/test/ActorValidationTest.java - first test in test class.

Comment: You're trying to make the method save() or your repository throw a checked exception that it doesn't declare. So even if the aspect declares it, that can't work. You need to make your exception extend RuntimeException.

Comment: That said, I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with this: Hibernate validator can validate entities before they are saved, and most of the time, changes to entities are made without ever calling save(), thus bypassing your checks.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you -  when `EntityValidationException` extends `RuntimeException` it worked, please place your comment as regular answer and then I can accept it.

Comment: @JBNizet as far as I know, in situation you describe changes to entities are made when transaction ends, and when I throw an exception it will be rolled back and changes would not be saved - but I may be wrong, cause I am front-end guy and don't do Hibernate/Spring profesionally.

Comment: Yes, that's right. But that's not the problem. The problem is that if you do, for example `Actor actor = repo.findById(1L); actor.setName(null);`, you'll never call the repository save() method, and the unwanted change will thus bypass your valication check and be saved in the database.

Comment: @JBNizet I always try to do explicite saves/updated (`save()` or `update()` ale always called), but you are right I didn't know about that, I have to validate DTOs or create another object which will be validated - thank you very much for pointing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to make the method `save()` or your repository throw a checked exception that it doesn't declare. So even if the aspect declares it, that can't work. You need to make your exception extend `RuntimeException`.